# Why does my validation not work with SubDocuments in mongoose under Typescript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to build different subdocuments, but unfortunately the validation doesn't work and probably the referencing doesn't work either. How can I solve the problem? Unfortunately I find too little mongoose in Typescript.

Here is my Code:

My main file:

```
import basicData, { IBasicData } from "./Basic/basicData.model";

export interface ICompany extends Document {
  basicData: IBasicData;
}

const CompanySchema = new Schema(
  {
    basicData: {
      type: Schema.Types,
      ref: "basicData",
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

export default mongoose.model<ICompany>("Company", CompanySchema);
```

My basicData file:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import { ITask } from "./task.model";
import tasks from "./task.model";

export interface IBasicData extends Document {
  task: ITask[];
  id: number;
  partnerWillingness: number;
  riskFactor: number;
  name: string;
}

const BasicDataSchema = new Schema({
  tasks: {
    type: Schema.Types.Array,
    ref: tasks,
    required: true,
  },
  _id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  partnerWillingness: { type: Number, required: true },
  riskFactor: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
});

export default mongoose.model<IBasicData>("basicData", BasicDataSchema);
```

and my tasks model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface ITask extends Document {
  title: string;
}

const TaskSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
});

export default mongoose.model<ITask>("tasks", TaskSchema);
```

my controller for get and add data:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import Company from "../models/company.model";

export const allCompanyData = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  Company.find()
    .then((items) => res.status(200).json(items))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error" + err));
};

export const addCompanyData = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  let item = new Company(req.body);
  item
    .save()
    .then(() => res.status(200).json("Data added"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error" + err));
};
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Compilation errors ? Runtime errors ? Please add a little more context.

Comment: This is the error, when i try to use my add function: "ErrorValidationError: basicData: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ name: 'test' }\" at path \"basicData\"" 

This error comes when I do: basicData: Schema.Type.ObjectId

Comment: If I leave it as in my question then it doesn't validate I can just leave out variables from basicData when I use the add function